# TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when trying to use unlink()

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

I need to do lots of protected range manipulation. I want to unlink the sheet to perform the operations on a local copy and sync it afterwards. This, however, doesn't work.

```python
spreadsheet = googleCloud.open_by_key(key)
worksheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
worksheets[4].unlink()
print(worksheets[4].get_value((1, 5)))
```

This code causes an exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/worksheet.py", line 293, in get_value
    include_tailing_empty_rows=True, value_render=value_render)[0][0]
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Without the unlink() the code works as expected. Am I using this method incorrectly? pygsheets from staging.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch values from an unlinked sheet.

When an unlinked sheet is linked these things happen.

1. The sheets properties json is synced to cloud.
2. The cells from `data_grid` is synced to cloud.
3. All the data update calls called during unlinked state is replayed.

So any cell data fetching functions won't work when a worksheet is unliked. If you want to get sheet data, use the `worksheet.data_grid`, it is save while unlinking. Its a matrix of cells.